Deployment Issue
Im trying to deploy a script but im getting a 'failed reconcilitation' message
[ VoterModule ] reconciliation failed ⛔
The module contains changes to executed futures:
VoterModule#Voter:
Artifact bytecodes have been changed
Consider modifying your module to remove the inconsistencies with deployed futures.
My code is as followed:
// 1. Import the `buildModule` function from the Hardhat Ignition module
const { buildModule } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition/modules");

// 2. Export a module using `buildModule`
module.exports = buildModule("VoterModule", (m) => {
    // 3. Use the `getAccount` method to select the deployer account
    const deployer = m.getAccount(0);

    // 4. Deploy the `Voter` contract
    const voter = m.contract("Voter", [], {
        from: deployer,
    });

    // 5. Return an object from the module
    return { voter };
});

